# sequelize-typescript vs TypeORM

Tags: node.js, typescript, orm, sequelize.js, typeorm

I am looking for "best" typescript ORM and my favorites are these two: Sequelize-Typescript and TypeORM.

My desired ORM should be at first place stable and well tested because it's gonna be used in a big project. Also, it's a longterm project with ~10 developers working on it, so it has to be programmer friendly and easy to maintain (including migrations and so on).

Sequelize has been proved over a long period of time in ORM field. Big companies contribute. On the other side, type orm is typescript-first library.

What do you think?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a place for such questions, so your question will probably be closed. I recommend you to use TypeORM if you want a maintenance heaver for yourself and your team. But best if you check both ORMs and decide which best fits for you

Comment: @pleerock Is "maintenance heaven" due to the use of TS or other factors too?

Comment: @pleerock I personally prefer [typeORM](http://typeorm.io/#/) when typescript is involved. I think Sequelize-Typescript does not fully utilize typescript. It just makes [sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/) "usable" with typescript. I had a really tough time setting up 'Sequelize-Typescript' project coming from oop background and then when I found out [typeORM](http://typeorm.io/#/), it felt like a breeze. I use [NestJS](https://nestjs.com) with [typeORM](http://typeorm.io/#/) for backend application.

Comment: @SanjuAus we use NestJS with TypeORM too. Imho it's the least painful way for C# programmer to create apps on nodejs

Comment: Sequalize have a limitation when creating/updating with association.
Here is a link stating same: https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/advanced-association-concepts/creating-with-associations/
But, typeORM is far batter in this case.
We can set 'cascade' parameter as true to achieve this.
Please keep this in mind when choosing one of those.